Display number of consecutive days a user has been active on the site
To encourage regular use, for logged in users, we'd like to display a line like this on the front end of the site:
"Activity streak: 8 days"
We'd like it to automatically update based on site activity. i.e. in the example above the user has done something on the site for 8 days in a row. Even just a pageview would be enough.
Our users can remain logged in so this can't be measured on actual logins, it needs to be measured on some kind of activity.
I have looked at gamification plugins but they are overengineered for a simple thing like this and don't seem to offer it anyway.
